# Как в eclipselink обновлять таблицу?

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, persistence, eclipselink

Как в eclipselink обновлять таблицу как в hibernate? Если я в коде в сущность добавляю поле, то в таблице должна добавиться колонка?

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
<persistence-unit name="VCB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/DefaultDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>
        <!--<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>-->
        <!--<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>-->
        <!--<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>-->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm - здесь описано только 3 варианта

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет [create-or-extend-tables](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#BABHEJJI):

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
```